# SQL PIVOT for two columns results in nulls in all pivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create this:

```
Last Name, First Name, Email1, Email2, Email3, Phone1, Phone2, Phone3
```

From this query:

```
;with CTE AS (
SELECT   FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Zip
FROM   Mother.dbo.People
Join   Mother.dbo.PeopleEmail on People.PeopleID = PeopleEmail.PeopleEmailID
Join   Mother.dbo.PeoplePhone on People.PeopleID = PeoplePhone.PeopleID
Where Zip IN ('34201','34202','34203','34205','34207','34208')
) Select * from CTE
PIVOT
(
       MAX(Email)
       FOR Email IN (Email1, Email2, Email3)
) AS E
PIVOT
(
        MAX(Phone)
        For Phone IN (Phone1, Phone2, Phone3)
) AS P;
```

However, it looks like all of my Email and Phone fields are coming back null.

For the record,

1. I'm using SQL Server 2017
2. The People Table has FirstName and Last Name, and it is One-to-Many to PeopleEmail (Email field) and PeoplePhone (Phone field).

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting.  can you please restate?  Thanks!

Comment: create cte without `zip ` column

Comment: Thanks. adjusted.  still coming back as nulls.

Comment: Ohh.. Okay. Let me try.

Comment: let me know, what you try here `MAX(Email) FOR Email IN (Email1, Email2, Email3)`.. Are you select max of three mail as `max(email) for email in ([a@gmail], [b@gmail], [c@gmail])`..?

Comment: let me put to you the output of the CTE.  first 15 records.

Comment: Most likely the email addresses take the form `someuser@somedomain.com` instead of `Email1`, `Email2` or `Email3` and you phone numbers aren't `Phone1`, `Phone2` and `Phone3`...

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with conditional aggregation.  But you need to enumerate the values in order to pivot them:

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, Email, Phone, p.Zip
from Mother.dbo.People p join
     (select PeopleId,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then phone end) as email3,
             max(case when seqnum = 1 then phone end) as phone1,
             max(case when seqnum = 2 then phone end) as phone2,
             max(case when seqnum = 3 then email end) as phone3
      from ((select pe.PeopleID, pe.email, null as phone,
                    row_number() over (partition by pe.PeopleID order by pe.PeopleEmailID) as seqnum
             from Mother.dbo.PeopleEmail pe
            ) union all
            (select pp.PeopleID, null as email, pp.phone,
                    row_number() over (partition by pp.PeopleID order by pp.PeoplePhoneId) as seqnum
             from Mother.dbo.PeopleEmail pe
            )
           ) em
      group by PeopleId
     ) em
     on p.PeopleID = em.PeopleEmailID
Where p.Zip IN ('34201', '34202', '34203', '34205', '34207', '34208');
```

EDIT:

Or you can phrase this as:

```
select p.FirstName, p.LastName, Email, Phone, p.Zip
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then phone end) as email3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then phone end) as phone1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then phone end) as phone2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then email end) as phone3
from ((select pe.PeopleID, pe.email, null as phone,
              row_number() over (partition by pe.PeopleID order by pe.PeopleEmailID) as seqnum
       from Mother.dbo.PeopleEmail pe
      ) union all
      (select pp.PeopleID, null as email, pp.phone,
              row_number() over (partition by pp.PeopleID order by pp.PeoplePhoneId) as seqnum
       from Mother.dbo.PeopleEmail pe
      )
     ) em join
     Mother.dbo.People p
     on p.PeopleID = em.PeopleEmailID
where p.Zip in ('34201', '34202', '34203', '34205', '34207', '34208');
```

Comment: you need to update here `max(case when seqnum = 3 then phone end) as email,`

Comment: This is awesome!.  is there any way to force the p.Zip filter prior to the join?  There's 3.2 Billion records in all of these tables.  Thanks!

Comment: @arcee123 . . . You can do the join essentially in the subquery and just add all the fields from `people` into the `group by` clause.

Comment: sorry, still trying to grip this feature.  can you please show me?  You basically have three independent queries from the three tables.  How do I limit the main query AND the sub queries so I don't attempt to row_number over a 1.2Bn Email table and a 1.5Bn Phone table?  Thanks again.